# Unable to get next sequence value

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having experience with Spring MVC first time and i face a error when i try to store the value in PostgreSQL. I am using sequence type of id.

"HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not get next sequence value; SQL [select nextval ('CUSTOMER_SEQ')]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value"

Here is my mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="java.mvc.domains.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
        <id name="id" column="ID" type="integer">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">CUSTOMER_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string"></property>
        <property name="email" column="EMAIL" type="string"></property>
        <property name="mobile" column="MOBILE" type="string"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

configuration file:

```
.....
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
                org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <array>
            <value>Customer.hbm.xml</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
......
```

Here is POJO:

```
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;

    // Getters and setters
```

Here is controller class:

```
public class CustomerController implements Controller {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

        String name = request.getParameter("name").trim();
        String email = request.getParameter("email").trim();
        String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile").trim();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName(name);
        customer.setEmail(email);
        customer.setMobile(mobile);

        Integer id = (Integer) hibernateTemplate.save(customer);

        return new ModelAndView("Customer", "id", id);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of error:

[image: Error ScreenShot]

But it works well with "assigned" type

Comment: Did you create 'CUSTOMER_SEQ' in the database side? if you run 'select nextval ('CUSTOMER_SEQ')' in the db, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate's PostgreSQL dialect isn't very bright. It doesn't know about your per-SERIAL sequences, and is assuming there's a global database-wide sequence called "hibernate_sequence" that it can use.

It appears that newer Hibernate versions may use the default per-table sequences when  GenerationType. IDENTITY is specified. and also check that the `CUSTOMER_SEQ` create properly or not